# Programmatically modifying maps based on inner condition

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have a map like this for example

```
const Map = new Map().set('123', [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ] ]).set('456', [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ], [ 'quux', 'corge' ] ]);
/* 
The structure of the Map looks like this:
    Map {
       '123' => [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ] ],
       '456' => [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ], [ 'quux', 'corge' ] ] 
   } 
*/
```

How would I go about deleting the array where the first nested element in the array === 'quux' so that it would return this?

```
Map {
    '123' => [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ] ],
    '456' => [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ] ] 
}
```

I know how to *remove* the item by doing

```
Map.set('456', (Map.get('456')).filter(array => array[0] !== 'quux'));
```

But this is only because I know which key ('456') has the element with 'quux' in it. I'm not sure how I would programmatically sweep through the Map then find the corresponding key and then remove the item. The keys and values in the Map will dynamic (but the structure will be the same), whereas the element to search for will be static, i.e: 'quux', what I mean by this is that the contents in the Map could vary, and I am simply performing a search and remove.

Comment: Use a loop. You should also learn about array functions like `forEach()`, `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Map` rather than an object?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am using a library that uses Maps so I have no choice but to use Map methods to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the map and if the wanted value is found, filter the array and assign the filtered array.

```js
const map = new Map([['123', [['foo', 'bar']]], ['456', [['baz', 'qux'], ['quux', 'corge']]]]);

map.forEach((v, k, m) => {
    if (v.some(a => a[0] === 'quux')) {
        m.set(k, v.filter(a => a[0] !== 'quux'));
    }
});

console.log([...map]);
```

Comment: That `[...map]` trick is neat—integrated it into my answer too. Learnt something new today!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the values of the `Map`, use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) on each value `v` to see if it includes an array whose first element is `quux`, and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) that array out if so:

```js
const map = new Map().set('123', [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ] ]).set('456', [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ], [ 'quux', 'corge' ] ]);

console.log("before", [...map]);

for (const v of map.values()) {
  const index = v.findIndex((a) => a[0] === "quux");
  
  if (index > -1) {
    v.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

console.log("after", [...map]);
```

Here’s the non-destructive alternative, which creates a new Map by taking the entries of the old one and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping the values to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the arrays we don’t want:

```js
const before = new Map().set('123', [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ] ]).set('456', [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ], [ 'quux', 'corge' ] ]);

console.log("before", [...before]);

const after = new Map([...before].map(([k, v]) => {
  return [k, v.filter((a) => a[0] !== "quux")];
}))

console.log("after", [...after]);
```

NOTE: One difference between the two approaches is that the second one will remove *all* arrays that have `quux` as their first element, whereas the second one will remove only the first such array. They can, of course, both be altered to fit whichever of the two options you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the key dynamically with a for of loop like this:

BTW open your devtools to checkout the new map since map cannot be properly displayed in the code snippet.

```js
const Map = new Map().set('123', [
  ['foo', 'bar']
]).set('456', [
  ['baz', 'qux'],
  ['quux', 'corge']
]);


for (let el of Map) {
  Map.set(el[0], (Map.get(el[0])).filter(array => array[0] !== 'quux'));
}


console.log(Map);
```

I hope this is what you wanted and otherwise you can comment and I will have a look at it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over key-value pair of the map, the value will have the outer array from which we can filter out the inner array having the value we are looking for. We can get the index of the inner array from the forEach function, using which we can use the splice function to remove the inner array from the outer array.

```
const map = new Map().set('123', [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ] ]).set('456', [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ], [ 'quux', 'corge' ] ]);
map.forEach((v, k)=>
{
     v.forEach((arr, idx)=> {
     if(arr.includes('quux')){
            v.splice(idx,1);
        }
    },)
});
console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's better from the performance point to always use `Array.prototype.filter` or use `Array.prototype.some` before filtering the array.

This solution just filters all arrays without checking an apperance of 'quux' before.

```
const map = new Map().set('123', [ ['foo', 'bar' ] ]).set('456', [ [ 'baz', 'qux' ], [ 'quux', 'corge' ] ]);

map.forEach((val, key) => {
  val = val.filter(arr => arr[0] !== 'quux');
  map.set(key, val);
});

console.log(map);
```